# PIGPIO: Can child process use the parent initilized pigpio library?

Tags: gpio, linux, uart

I have a parent process (which is a basic tcp server). This process calls gpioInitialise() before forking a child process which polls gpio pins for input. 
After forking the child, the parent process read()s a socket in a while loop.
The parent also should be able to access gpio via the library.

Now, both processes will run in parallel and are polling for different events. However, when I try to access the library from the child, I get:

[code]2014-11-06 09:53:09 sigHandler: Unhandled signal 11, terminating[/code]

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have commented at [raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=636272#p636272).  I haven't tried what you describe but generally only one process should be using the gpioXXX functions, other processes should be talking via sockets or pipes.

Comment: Thanks Joan. I read your reply there. I have changed my code to use the daemon.

Comment: An alternative, which may be closer to what you are trying to do, is to use the [gpioStartThread](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioStartThread) function.